# Bazel build error "No such file or directory"

Tags: java, exception, build, bazel, nosuchfileexception

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded and installed bazel according to the [official bazel guide](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html) and after that I downloaded the first [tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/java.html) for building a Java project but it didn't work. I got this exception:

```
unexpected pipe read status: (error: 2): No such file or directory
Server presumed dead. Now printing '/home/jingw222/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jingw222/ada033fd33c06190d78b77ab4907f1d0/server/jvm.out':
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeExecutor.skyFunctions(SkyframeExecutor.java:348)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeExecutor.init(SkyframeExecutor.java:586)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutor.init(SequencedSkyframeExecutor.java:252)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutor.create(SequencedSkyframeExecutor.java:211)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutor.create(SequencedSkyframeExecutor.java:162)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutorFactory.create(SequencedSkyframeExecutorFactory.java:48)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.WorkspaceBuilder.build(WorkspaceBuilder.java:81)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.initWorkspace(BlazeRuntime.java:204)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.newRuntime(BlazeRuntime.java:1023)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.createBlazeRPCServer(BlazeRuntime.java:850)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.serverMain(BlazeRuntime.java:789)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.main(BlazeRuntime.java:570)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.BazelMain.main(BazelMain.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.lang.management.UnixExtendedOperatingSystem incompatible with com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ResourceUsage.<clinit>(ResourceUsage.java:45)
    ... 13 more
```

What can caouse the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8092) issue, and finally I realized, that I need to download the jdk manually. So I used this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

After that I built it again, and it worked well.

Comment: Yes unfortunately we do not handle running with JDK-9 yet but we are working on it.

Comment: @DamienMartin-guillerez can't bendaf use a bazel installer which is bundled with the jdk?

Comment: We do not package the JDK in the debian installer.